# Testing WPF ViewModel with Xunit

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, xunit

Recently I was put on new a team at work and the lead told me to write unit tests for the code they had written. I'm really not sure where to start. The application is a WPF written in C#. I'm a newbie to both WPF and C#. They mentioned using Xunit.

Here is first two functions of the class. There is mix of protected and public functions i have to unit test,

The class type is `public class DataTableModel<T> : ViewModelBase`

```
public DataTableModel()
        {
            //Setup Drag and Drop Commands:
            RecordReceivedCommand = new DataTableReceivedCommand<T>(this);
            RecordRemovedCommand = new DataTableRemovedCommand<T>(this);
            RecordInsertedCommand = new DataTableInsertedCommand<T>(this);
            View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Records);
            
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// This method sets up the properties for the table. By default, the first DisplayOption is selected, no search criteria is applies, and only 10 records should be returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="displayOption">The selected display option</param>
        protected void InstantiateTable(int displayOption = 0)
        {
            _displayOption = displayOption;
            _searchCriteria = "";
            _displayAmount = "10";
            _currentPage = 1;
            _userMessage = "Retrieving data...";
            
            TriggerUpdate();
        }
```

These functions are called from above so I thought I'd include them.

```
/// <summary>
        /// This method is responsible for handling the updates to the recordset that the DataGrid will display.
        /// Upon changes to the search criteria, display amount, display option and the current page, this method will be triggered
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resetPage">Inidicates whether the grid should return to page 1.</param>
        protected void TriggerUpdate(bool resetPage = false)
        {

            _currentPage = resetPage ? 1 : _currentPage; //only reset to the first page if indicated
            UserMessage = "Retrieving data...";

            //Retrieve the records if the delegate has been set
            GetRecords?.Invoke();
            UserMessage = Records.Count == 0 ? "No data found" : "";

            Message_ZIndex = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserMessage) ? 1 : -1;

            //update the page navigations button's settings when the pages are reset
            UpdatePagination();

        }
 /// <summary>
        /// Update the ability to navigate through the datatable's pages. 
        /// Upon changes the the search criteria, display amount, display option, the number of pages and the current page, this method will be
        /// triggered
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdatePagination()
        {
            if (Pages > 1)
            {
                if (_currentPage == 1)
                {
                    GoToFirstPage = false;
                    GoToPrevPage = false;
                    GoToNextPage = true;
                    GoToLastPage = true;

                }
                else if (_currentPage == Pages)
                {
                    GoToFirstPage = true;
                    GoToPrevPage = true;
                    GoToNextPage = false;
                    GoToLastPage = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    GoToFirstPage = true;
                    GoToPrevPage = true;
                    GoToNextPage = true;
                    GoToLastPage = true;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                GoToFirstPage = false;
                GoToPrevPage = false;
                GoToNextPage = false;
                GoToLastPage = false;

            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get's the information for the datatable's columns
        /// (NOTE: This method is currently only called via ".Invoke" within the DataTable control.)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A List of the DataTableDisplay attributes for the columns in the table</returns>
        public List<DataTableDisplay> GetTableColumnInformation()
        {

            List<DataTableDisplay> attributes = new List<DataTableDisplay>();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                DataTableDisplay attr = property.GetCustomAttribute<DataTableDisplay>(false);
                if (attr != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr.ColumnTitle))
                {
                    attributes.Add(attr);
                }
            }

            return attributes;

            
        }
```

At first I wanted to test the constructor, but then I didn't know how to check for the command vars so i moved on to the `InstantiateTable` function. This is what i got. Still having to create object so using the Constructor but when i tried calling `x.InstantiateTable()` I noticed it was protected so I cant do that.

Test case for creating an DataTableModel Object. It had dynamic type  so i just made it int.

```
[Fact]
        public void DataTableModel_Created()
        {
            DataTableModel<int> x = new DataTableModel<int>();
            Assert.Equal(0, x.DisplayOption);
            Assert.Equal("", x.SearchCriteria);
            Assert.Equal("10", x.DisplayAmount);
            Assert.Equal(1, x.CurrentPage);
            Assert.Equal("Retrieving data...", x.UserMessage);
            
        }
```

Another protected function i have to unit test.

```
protected List<T> UpdateTable(List<T> data)
        {
            
            _totalCount = data.Count;
            int recordLimit = String.IsNullOrEmpty(DisplayAmount) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(DisplayAmount);
            int startingRecord = recordLimit == 0 ? 0 : (_currentPage == 1 ? 1 : 1 + (recordLimit * (_currentPage - 1)));
            int recordsToSkip = (CurrentPage - 1) * recordLimit;
            int endingRecord = recordLimit == 0 ? 0 : recordLimit > _totalCount ? _totalCount : startingRecord + recordLimit - 1;
            Pages = recordLimit == 0 ? 0 : _totalCount <= recordLimit ? 1 : _totalCount % recordLimit > 0 ? (_totalCount / recordLimit) + 1 : _totalCount / recordLimit;
            List<T> displayRecords = data.Skip(recordsToSkip).Take(recordLimit).ToList();
            DisplayMessage = endingRecord <= _totalCount ? $"Showing {(displayRecords.Count == 0 ? 0 : startingRecord)} to {endingRecord} of {_totalCount} entries" : $"Showing {startingRecord} to {_totalCount} of {_totalCount} entries";
            return displayRecords;
           
        }
```

And a delegate function? I'm supposed to test

```
public delegate List<T> Filter(List<T> data);
```

I am not sure how to approach. The few unit tests i did in university were basic objects and didn't call other objects and what not. I have read about mocking and stubbing objects, I think it may be good to mock database to populate the tables.

Comment: Your view-model doesn't seem to be using any kind of DI, so it isn't really unit-testable... especially as you seem to be using databases and external IO via `static` members (which is a big _no-no_). You need to significantly refactor that class.

Comment: Also, be-aware that `INotifyPropertyChanged` events and bindings behave differently in WPF compared to raising/subscribing to events in a testing scenario because of how the `Dispatcher` works.

Answer (score -1):

Do not unit-test functions. Unit-test view-models.

A view-model exposes properties and commands which are bound by XAML to GUI controls so that the user can interact with them.

All these properties and commands are already `public`, otherwise they would not be visible from XAML, so your tests can access them too.

Most C# programmers will not think twice before converting `private` and `protected` to `public`, or converting to `internal` and then using `InternalsVisibleTo`, but in my opinion that's all misguided. We must be testing against the interface, not against the implementation; therefore, we must be engaging in black-box testing, not white-box testing.

When it comes to testing view-models in WPF, this means you should only test things that are exposed to XAML.

So, your tests should set values to view-model properties as if these values were set by GUI controls, invoke view-model commands as if these commands were triggered by GUI buttons.

Then, your tests should examine nothing but how the values of view-model properties change as a result. That's what the user would see on the screen.